# How to switch to an older pyspark version?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pip, homebrew

I have pyspark 2.4.4 installed on my Mac.

```
➜  ~ pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_222
Branch
Compiled by user  on 2019-08-27T21:21:38Z
Revision
Url
Type --help for more information.
```

I need to revert back to an older version 2.3.2.

```
➜  ~ pip install pyspark==2.3.2
Collecting pyspark==2.3.2
Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.7 in /workspace/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyspark==2.3.2) (0.10.7)
Installing collected packages: pyspark
  Found existing installation: pyspark 2.4.4
    Can't uninstall 'pyspark'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed pyspark-2.3.2
```

While running above command seems like it installs pyspark-2.3.2, but doesn't overwrite the existing pyspark 2.4.4 version. And when I check at this path `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/` I only see `2.4.4` sub-directory, I do not want to delete that directory since it contains all the configurations at `libexec/conf/spark-defaults.conf` and jars at `libexec/jars`.

Is there a neat and robust way to switch apache-spark versions on Mac ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend using python virtual environments.

Comment: Using Anaconda distribution should help you to manage packages easily. Pip is not so successful on managing OS native packages like require system dependencies.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to keep the 2.4.4 jars and conf but use the 2.3.2 python tool?

Answer (score 2):

Try `--force-reinstall` flag. Your command should look like

```
pip install --force-reinstall pyspark==2.3.2
```